# Publish app to specific region

Tags: google-play, app-store, publishing

I'm developing an app and at the beginning I want it to be available only in a specific region (my city). Is it possible?

I want to publish my app both in Google Play and Apple App Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On both *Google Play* and *Apple App Store* you can limit installations only to certain country.